# Ruby: The simplest way of getting the full constant name of all constants within an object (Class or Module)

Tags: ruby, constants

I have the following Structure:

```
module SomeMod::SubMod
  module Mod1; end
  module Mod2; end
end
```

I want to  get all  constants of SubMod, but I want a fully qualified reference to the Constant (ie. `SomeMod::SubMod::Mod1`)  Currently I'm doing this:

```
SomeMod::SubMod.constants.map{ |constant| SomeMod::SubMod.const_get constant }
```

Can someone improve on this?  Can I remove the duplicate reference to `SomeMod::SubMod`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SomeMod::SubMod.module_eval{ constants.map{|c| const_get c} }
```

It's not really that much shorter, though.